# Create a page fit div and a child evenly padded inside

Tags: html, css

I would like to create two divs, one inside the other with equal padding on all sides of the child.  Like so

```
<div>
    <div>Foo</div> 
</div>
```

So that the result looks like

```
----------------------------
|                          |
|  |--------------------|  |
|  |                    |  |   <----  There is 1em padding on the inner
|  |  Foo               |  |          container too
|  |                    |  |
|  |                    |  |
|  |--------------------|  |
|                          |   <----  This is the window height,
----------------------------          the padding is 1em on all sides;
```

How do I do this in CSS?

Right now I am stuck on this layout, missing the bottom padding

[image]

With this code

```
<div class="more-padded full-height blue-green fixed">
    <div class="more-padded full-height light-tan more-rounded light-border">Foo</div>
</div>
```

and style

```
.more-padded {
    padding: 1em;
}

.full-height {
    height: 100%;
}

.blue-green {
    background-color: rgba(153, 204, 204, 1);
}

.light-tan {
    background-color: rgba(239, 235, 214, 1);
}

.more-rounded {
    -moz-border-radius: 1em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
}
```

Comment: I think you want `padding:1em;` unless I'm crazy, in the css for the top div.

Comment: Thats a part of it, but there is getting the outer div to fill the window size exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing):`border-box;` so that the width and height properties include the padding and border

HTML

```
 <div id="parent">
       <div id="child">Foo</div> 
    </div>
```

CSS

```
* {
margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
html, body {
  height:100%;
}
#parent {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  height:100%;
  padding:1em;
  background:hotpink;
}
#child {
  height:100%;
  background:dodgerblue;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9ktwz06b/1/)

Comment: The border box did something interesting, but when I put 1 em padding on the child it ends up running off the bottom.  http://imgur.com/g08YsGz  How do I get the padding on the inner div too?

Comment: @DavidWilliams Simply apply the same for inner div as well http://jsfiddle.net/9ktwz06b/1/

Answer (score 1):

Hi for equal padding use the following code.

Live demo is on http://jsfiddle.net/adarshkr/fqm83gms/5/

html

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <p><a href="http://www.adarshkr.com">Equal padding adarsh</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
body{
    background:#ddd
}
.outer{
     background:#eee;
    padding:20px
}
.inner{
     background:#000;
    padding:20px;
    color:#fff
}
.inner a{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now that I am on an actual computer:

I think you want this: ([Js Fiddle For Reference](http://jsfiddle.net/9ktwz06b/))

```
body,html{
    height:100%;width:100%;
}

body{
    padding:1em;
}

body >div{
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: So the box with the "Hi" goes all the way to the right, how to get it to stop and have the 1em padding on the right?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand; It has a 1em padding on both sides? jsFiddle is just weird and insists on the scrollbar.